# Sockets - Not sending/receiving data

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm starting a socket program, and am in the process of setting up a Server and two types of Clients (a requester and an arbiter). I'm in the middle of testing the connections, but they aren't quite working. Right now I just have a button for each form: an "Accept" button for the Arbiter and "Request" for the Requester. Each button should cause a popup on the other form, but neither is working. Also, I've noticed that when I close all programs, the Server is still running in my processes. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the Server code:

```
namespace FPPLNotificationServer
{
    class Server
    {

        static Socket listenerSocket;
        static List<ClientData> _clients;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting server on " + Packet.GetIP4Address());
            listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _clients = new List<ClientData>();
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Packet.GetIP4Address()), 4242);
            listenerSocket.Bind(ip);

            Thread listenThread = new Thread(ListenThread);
            listenThread.Start();
        }

        static void ListenThread()
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                listenerSocket.Listen(0);
                _clients.Add(new ClientData(listenerSocket.Accept()));
            }
        }

        public static void Data_IN(object cSocket)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = (Socket)cSocket;

            byte[] Buffer;
            int readBytes;

            for (;;)
            {
                try
                {
                    Buffer = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];
                    readBytes = clientSocket.Receive(Buffer);

                    if(readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        Packet packet = new Packet(Buffer);
                        DataManager(packet);
                    }
                }catch(SocketException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void DataManager(Packet p)
        {
            switch (p.packetType)
            {
                case Packet.PacketType.Notification:
                    foreach(ClientData c in _clients)
                    {
                        c.clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    class ClientData
    {
        public Socket clientSocket;
        public Thread clientThread;
        public string id;

        public ClientData()
        {
            this.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            clientThread = new Thread(Server.Data_IN);
            clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
            SendRegistrationPacket();
        }

        public ClientData(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            this.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            clientThread = new Thread(Server.Data_IN);
            clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
            SendRegistrationPacket();
        }

        public void SendRegistrationPacket()
        {
            Packet p = new Packet(Packet.PacketType.Registration, "server");
            p.Gdata.Add(id);
            clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

ServerData

```
namespace FPPLNotificationServerData
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Packet
    {

        public List<String> Gdata;
        public int packetInt;
        public bool packetBool;
        public string senderID;
        public PacketType packetType;
        public string PlantName, ProductSegment, ProductCustomer;
        public int PlantNumber;
        public string ProductNumber, ProductAltNumber;
        public string ProductDiscription;
        public int ProductLine;
        public string ProductClass, ProductLocation;
        public int ProductMcDFactor;

        public Packet(PacketType type, String senderID)
        {
            Gdata = new List<string>();
            this.senderID = senderID;
            this.packetType = type;
        }

        public Packet(byte[] packetBytes)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(packetBytes);

            Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            ms.Close();
            this.Gdata = p.Gdata;
            this.senderID = p.senderID;
            this.packetType = p.packetType;
            this.packetBool = p.packetBool;
            this.packetInt = p.packetInt;
        }

        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, this);
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            return bytes;
        }

        public static string GetIP4Address()
        {
            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach(IPAddress i in ips)
            {
                if(i.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return i.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "127.0.0.1";
        }

        public enum PacketType
        {
            Registration,
            Chat,
            Notification,
            Request,
            ArbiterDecision,
            Accept,
            Decline
        }
    }
}
```

Request Class:

```
namespace FPPLRequestClient
{
    public partial class frm_Request : Form
    {

        public static Socket master;
        public static string name;
        public static string id;
        public bool isConnected;

        public frm_Request()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string IP = "127.0.0.1";
            master = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 4242);
            try
            {
                master.Connect(ipEP);
                isConnected = true;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                isConnected = false;
            }

            string connectionStatus = isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected";
            this.lbl_Status.Text = "Status: " + connectionStatus;

            Thread t = new Thread(Data_IN);
            t.Start();

        }

        void Data_IN()
        {
            byte[] Buffer;
            int readBytes;

            while (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    Buffer = new byte[master.SendBufferSize];
                    readBytes = master.Receive(Buffer);
                    if(readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        DataManager(new Packet(Buffer));
                    }
                }catch(SocketException ex)
                {
                    isConnected = false;
                    this.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }//END DATA IN

        void DataManager(Packet p)
        {
            switch (p.packetType)
            {
                case Packet.PacketType.Registration:
                    id = p.Gdata[0];
                    break;
                case Packet.PacketType.Accept:
                    //MessageBox.Show(p.ProductNumber);
                    this.lbl_Status.Text = p.ProductNumber + " accepted";
                    Invalidate();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Request_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Packet p = new Packet(Packet.PacketType.Request, id);
            p.ProductNumber = "123456";
            master.Send(p.ToBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

Arbiter Class:

```
namespace FPPLArbiterClient
{
    public partial class frm_Arbiter : Form
    {
        public static Socket master;
        public static string name;
        public static string id;
        public bool isConnected;

        public frm_Arbiter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string IP = "127.0.0.1";
            master = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 4242);
            try
            {
                master.Connect(ipEP);
                isConnected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                isConnected = false;
            }

            string connectionStatus = isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected";
            this.lbl_Status.Text = "Status: " + connectionStatus;

            Thread t = new Thread(Data_IN);
            t.Start();

        }

        void Data_IN()
        {
            byte[] Buffer;
            int readBytes;

            while (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    Buffer = new byte[master.SendBufferSize];
                    readBytes = master.Receive(Buffer);
                    if(readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        DataManager(new Packet(Buffer));
                    }
                }catch(SocketException ex)
                {
                    isConnected = false;
                    this.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }//END DATA IN

        void DataManager(Packet p)
        {
            switch (p.packetType)
            {
                case Packet.PacketType.Registration:
                    id = p.Gdata[0];
                    break;
                case Packet.PacketType.Request:
                    MessageBox.Show(p.ProductNumber + " Requested from " + p.senderID);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sending acceptance of 126456");
            Packet p = new Packet(Packet.PacketType.Accept, id);
            p.ProductNumber = "123456";
            master.Send(p.ToBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first dive into socket programming.

Comment: I have changed the IP's to 127.0.0.1 for anonymity

Answer (score 0):

To start with your last question first, Receive will block until data becomes available unless you specify a timeout. Since your threads are foreground threads, this will prevent your application from terminating. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx. Either use a timeout, and/or make your threads background threads causing them to terminate when you close your application's main thread. Set the created thread's IsBackground property to true to achieve this. (Also, in the article above notice the paragraph about Shutdown and the Receive method returning an empty array. This is your hint to gracefully close the connection on your side).

The TCP/IP stack will send data at its own discretion (Nagle's algorithm), meaning you'll occasionally receive a buffer containing several or partial messages. Since you have "silent" error handling in your thread, perhaps your thread terminates prematurely because of a corrupted message? Place everything you receive in a buffer and check the buffer for complete messages in a separate step/thread before passing them on to your message handler.

No clear answers here I'm afraid, but if the check for corrupted messages doesn't help, look at the Socket samples on MSDN. It's probably just a tiny detail you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

you are making a fundamental and common TCP error. TCP is a byte oriented streaming protocol, not message oriented. Your receive code assumes that it receives one `Packet` when it reads. This is not guaranteed, you might receive 1 byte, 20 bytes, or whatever. You must loop in the receive till you get all of one message. This means you have to know when you have read it all. Either there needs to be a header or some sentinel at the end.